# Reaching a HTTPS Rest api using Spring RestTemplate by-passing host verification

Tags: spring, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate, resttemplate

I've read many things about this problem, and I thought I had found the most simple workaround (last code example from here : http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl), but it doesn't work.

Here is how I declare my RestTemplate with hostname verification turned off (and a proxy setting) :

```
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
      .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
      .setProxy(new HttpHost("10.xx.xx.xx", 3128, "http"))
      .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return builder.requestFactory(requestFactory).build();

    //return builder.build();
  }
```

And here is the code to create my POST request :

```
  LoginResponse loginResponse = restTemplate.postForObject("https://interflex.svc.suezsmartsolutions.com/path/to/my/api", loginRequest, LoginResponse.class);
```

And here is the exception I get (just like if I had not turned off hostname verifier) :

```
16:15:27 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:771 - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://interflex.svc.suezsmartsolutions.com/path/to/api": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:387)
    at hello.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:375)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:416)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:659)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Could someone help me get rid of this exception ?

Also I don't know why this exception appears in the first place, since the root CA used to generate the site certificate (VeriSign) is present in my truststore (cacerts) (the intermediate authority is not present though, could it be the reason ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "yes you need the intermediate authority in your truststore, not only the root CA".

Answer (score 1):

Simple Fix, just skip the certificate

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems more related to a certificate issue than to proxy configuration.
Anyway in my projects I'm using this configuration:

```
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory factory)
    {
        RestTemplate result = new RestTemplate(factory);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory() throws Exception
    {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception
    {
        int timeout = new Integer(env.getProperty("web.http.client.timeout"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
                //I load a JSON where I specify the name and the PWD of keystores I want to use
        String keystores = "keyStoreInfo.json";
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm = null;
        if(StringUtils.hasText(keystores))
        {
            Resource jsonRes = new ClassPathResource(keystores);
            if( jsonRes.exists() )
            {
                List<KeyStoreInfo> ksInfo = objectMapper().readValue(jsonRes.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<List<KeyStoreInfo>>()
                {
                });
                SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                List<KeyManager> keymanagers = new ArrayList<KeyManager>();
                for (KeyStoreInfo ksi : ksInfo)
                {
                    String keystoreName = ksi.getNomeKeyStore();
                    String keyStorePwd = ksi.getPasswordKeyStore();
                    if( StringUtils.hasText(keystoreName) )
                    {
                        Resource keystoreRes = new ClassPathResource(keystoreName);
                        KeyMaterial km = new KeyMaterial(keystoreRes.getInputStream(), keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
                        KeyStore clientStore = km.getKeyStore();
                        KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                        kmfactory.init(clientStore, keyStorePwd != null ? keyStorePwd.toCharArray() : null);
                        keymanagers.addAll(Arrays.asList(kmfactory.getKeyManagers()));
                    }
                }
                if( !keymanagers.isEmpty() )
                {

                    X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                            return null;
                        }

                    };      
                    sslCtx.init(keymanagers.toArray(new KeyManager[keymanagers.size()]), new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtx);   
                    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("https", sslConnectionFactory).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();
                    pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if( logger.isInfoEnabled() )
                    {
                        logger.info("Nessun keystore presente nel JSON di configurazione {}. Creo un PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager di default",keystores);
                    }
                    pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();                 
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( logger.isInfoEnabled() )
            {
                logger.info("Nessun keystore da caricare. Creo un PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager di default");
            }
            pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        }
        HttpClientBuilder hcb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        pcm.closeIdleConnections(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).setConnectTimeout(timeout).build();
        hcb.setDefaultRequestConfig(config);
        hcb.setConnectionManager(pcm).setConnectionManagerShared(true);
        boolean proxyEnable = new Boolean(env.getProperty("web.http.client.proxyEnable"));
        if (proxyEnable)
        {
            int proxyPort = new Integer(env.getProperty("web.http.client.portProxy"));
            String proxyHost = env.getProperty("web.http.client.hostProxy");
            BasicCredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            AuthScope scope = new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort);
            String usernameProxy = env.getProperty("web.http.client.usernameProxy");
            String passwordProxy = env.getProperty("web.http.client.passwordProxy");
            if (StringUtils.hasText(usernameProxy) && StringUtils.hasText(passwordProxy))
            {

                UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(usernameProxy, passwordProxy);
                credentialProvider.setCredentials(scope, credentials);
            }
            ProxyRoutePlanner proxyRoutPlanner = new ProxyRoutePlanner(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort), env.getProperty("web.http.client.urlNotProxy"));
            hcb.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider).setRoutePlanner(proxyRoutPlanner);
        }
        WsKeepAliveStrategy cas = new WsKeepAliveStrategy();
        cas.setTimeout(new Long(timeout));
        hcb.setKeepAliveStrategy(cas);
        httpClient = hcb.build();
        return httpClient;
    }
```

Where `WsKeepAliveStrategy` is:

```
public class WsKeepAliveStrategy implements ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
{
    private Long timeout;

    @Override
    public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
    {
        return timeout;
    }

    public void setTimeout(Long timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

}
```

and `ProxyRoutePlanner` is:

```
public class ProxyRoutePlanner extends DefaultProxyRoutePlanner
{

    private List<String> urlsNotProxy = null;
    private boolean useAlwaysSuper = false;

    public ProxyRoutePlanner(HttpHost proxy, String urlNotProxy)
    {
        super(proxy);
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(urlNotProxy))
            this.useAlwaysSuper = true;
        else
        {
            this.urlsNotProxy = Arrays.asList(urlNotProxy.split(","));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HttpRoute determineRoute(HttpHost host, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException
    {

        String hostname = host.getHostName();
        if (this.useAlwaysSuper || this.urlsNotProxy.contains(hostname) == false)
            return super.determineRoute(host, request, context);// Super method
        // with proxy
        if ("http".equals(host.getSchemeName()))
            return new HttpRoute(host);// Direct Route
        HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
        RequestConfig config = clientContext.getRequestConfig();
        InetAddress local = config.getLocalAddress();
        return new HttpRoute(host, local, true);
    }

}
```

I'm using this configuration and I'm having no issue

In any case you should check what kind of certificate is necessary to use in your rest invocation

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Well, my question is very precise, and your answer is very broad, that's what I can say. Also, I don't know what u mean by "you should check what kind of certificate is necessary to use in your rest invocation", you can see the certificate yourself by reaching the URL I provide. The certificate is signed by VeriSign, and I can find the root CA in my truststore. Anyway, I try to disable host verification since I'm not implementing a browser, just a simple rest client for a single domain.

Comment: I just posted my configuration and by using this configuration I have no issue both using certificates and behind a proxy. You are free to use it or not use it. In your case, instead, the exception is pretty clear.. it's not the proxy but the certificate chain so what I was suggesting to you is to check it

Comment: You are answering to the title of the question and doesnt want to read anything else I'm writing do you ? Don't guess, just watch the certificate yourself and see it's valid man.

Comment: Also, as I said just before, by-passing all verification is a totally valid way for my usecase, so truststore and keystore settings are not useful to me.